# Can I reference a range, within a function, that goes down to infinity?

Tags: excel

E.g. I put in cell O3 [=SUM(O4:O15901)]

Let's say I may copy this formula elsewhere, or add more cells in column O in the future. Is there any way to just tell it to go all the way down, e.g. [=SUM(O4:O*)] or something?

Comment: Supposing it were possible - what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I want to make my code more robust and extensible. I mention in the question: "Let's say I may copy this formula elsewhere, or add more cells in column O in the future."

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I misinterpreted "to infinity" as implying you were after some sort of infinite summation... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `=SUM(O:O)-SUM(O1:O2)`

SUM ignores text, so it may not be necessary to subtract `SUM(O1:O2)`, but just in case, you can include it

EDIT: Just realized you were putting this formula in cell O3... This will give you a circular reference.

Try this one: `=SUM(OFFSET(O4, 0, 0, ROWS(O:O)-3))`

Comment: this one better since it's not volatile: `=SUM(O4:INDEX(O:O,ROWS(O:O)-3))`

Comment: The `-3` in that excludes the last 3 rows, so it should be `=SUM(O4:INDEX(O:O,ROWS(O:O)))` for that one

Comment: @simoco Both of your option won't sum the LAST 3 rows you are NOT skipping the first 3 rows as I think you think you are doing by using -3. Also why even bother using `ROWS(O:O)-3)` as the value will NEVER change. It makes more sense to simply use hard coded value.

Comment: @user2140261 Having a hard-coded value limits the version requirements

Comment: @noah Limits it into 2 version, all unsupported version before 2007, and all current version after. Not that big of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

When I have situations like this, I will see if using the built-in `Tables` feature is an option (for design reasons). That way you can sum the column of the table and it will automatically expand when more rows are added.

i.e.
`=SUM(myTable[sumColumn])`

Comment: That format only works in 2010, in 2007 it is slightly different. I Original was going to add this method to my answer also, but the way the OP's data is set up (he wants sum of a column above the data, and in such a more central column (O) I figured his data was of a format that wouldn't work well with this. +1 anyways it is a better solution ***If it can work for OP***

Comment: It should work just the same in 2007 (some filtering differences, but summing is just the same). See [Microsoft Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/organize-data-into-excel-2007-tables-HA010217630.aspx). You can use the table references to sum anywhere in the workbook, they do not have to be associated with the exact table location, so he can put the formula I listed above the table as he describes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2007+ you mine as well just use `=Sum(O4:O1048576)`

as Excel will only sum the used range anyway and throw out all the extra cells.

Comment: So this won't slow down my functions?

Comment: In a sum function if you specify an array or cell reference as a parameter, only numbers in that array or reference are counted. Empty cells, logical values, or text in the array or reference are ignored.

Comment: It will slow things down, but potentially less, than volatile functions that would be needed to make it dynamic.

Comment: @guitarthrower It won't, as stated in my question as long as it is a version of excel 2007+, Microsoft updated there array methods and it will only evaluate down to the last *used* row. So even if I use `=SUM(A:A)` if I have data only upto row 10 excel (2007+) will stop looking at cells on the 10th row by using special handling for the empty cells. It was a feature introduced into 2007.

Comment: There are many known issues with Excel and it's idea of a Last Used Row. I agree with you on theory that it may not cause issues, but it's not safe to assume that it won't hurt performance.

Comment: @guitarthrower The empty cell handling and the Used Range are two completly different things.

Comment: Thanks @user2140261. I was curious and found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx). You're right about only using the last used range, with the exception of Array formulas which calculate the entire row. Thanks for the heads up on that!